# A question from CFT (possibly due to the English expressions)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, conformal-field-theory, textbook-erratum

I am currently reading the book ''[Conformal Field Theory](https://books.google.de/books?id=keUrdME5rhIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=conformal%20field%20theory&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0z7DVptnNAhXmD8AKHSXmAEEQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=conformal%20field%20theory&f=false)'' and encountered a description about which I am very confused. I am afraid to say, this may be due to the fact that I am not a native English speaker.

On pp.6, it says:

> However, the field theory describing a statistical system (like the Ising model) lives in one spatial dimension **less** than the statistical system itself, since time constitutes an extra dimension inherently incorporated in the quantum description of the field theory.

Here, let's say, the statistical system we want to describe is 3 dimensional. Then according to the author, the field theory should lives in 2 dimensional space, right? But this sentence is followed immediately by

> Critical quantum phenomena on which the methods of two-dimensional conformal field theory can be applied are thus one-dimensional, like the spin chain described above.

Now, the statistical system is 1 dimensional while the field is 2 dimensional. That is to say, the field lives in one spatial dimension **more** than the statistical system. Even if we wick rotate back into the Minkowskian spacetime, the field lives in 1 dimensional space (now 1+1 spacetime) and not one spatial dimension **less** than the statistical system. Where is going wrong for my understandings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that the language is very confusing - I'm a native English speaker, and it also took me a while to understand what they were saying.  When they talk about the dimension of "the statistical system itself," they mean the space*time* dimension.  So if a system has two *spatial* dimensions, then it has three dimensions total (including time), and the statistical field theory has one dimension less than that - back to two again, the number of spatial dimensions.

There are two ways to intuitively understand this:

(1) If you think about real time, the "statistical mechanics describing finite-temperature phenomena" deals with thermodynamic equilibrium, which by definition does not depend on time.  So you can ignore the time dimension (or more precisely, average over it) and only focus on the fluctuations in the spatial dimensions.

(2) If you think about imaginary time in the Matsubara formalism of statistical field theory, then the imaginary time dimension is periodic with period $\beta$.  At finite temperature, this dimension is compact.  But at phase transitions, all correlation lengths diverge, and so they become infinitely larger than the circumference $\beta$ in the imaginary time direction.  So you can neglect the finite circumference $\beta$ entirely and ignore that dimension, and only consider the spatial dimensions, which are extended.  This is why we say that any finite temperature, no matter how low, phase transitions are essentially classical, even if quantum effects are significant away from the transition at that temperature.  On the other hand, at zero temperature, the imaginary time direction is infinitely long and on the same footing as the spatial dimensions, so we need to consider it even with arbitrarily long correlation lengths.

Comment: Thank you very much for your useful answer. Regarding ''But at phase transitions, all correlation lengths diverge, and so they become infinitely larger than the circumference β in the imaginary time direction. So you can neglect the finite circumference β entirely and ignore that dimension...'', why the infinite correlation length makes the finite $\beta$ can be neglected?

Comment: The rough answer is that the correlation length sets the natural scale at which you should view the system.  So if you have a very thin cylinder, and you "zoom out" to the scale of the correlation length, which is much longer than the cylinder's circumference, then the cylinder just "looks like" a line - you can no longer resolve the circumferential direction, so you effectively "lose" that dimension.

Comment: The more precise answer is that if the correlation length is much longer than the cylinder's circumference, than you would have to wrap around the circumference many times before two points become uncorrelated.  But this is impossible, because the cylinder is periodic.  So the points on each small circle around the cylinder must be perfectly correlated - i.e. there are no fluctuations in the circumferential direction.  But in that case, you can just treat all the points lying on a small circle as a single point, so you once again "lose" the circumferential dimension.

Comment: Your explanation is very enlightening. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am bit puzzled. We routinely apply CFT techniques to non-relativistic systems, where there is no fundamental energy-distance relation. $\beta$ is naturally (inverse) energy, so how precisely are you comparing it to the correlation length?

Comment: @PeterKravchuk Even in a nonrelativistic system, when the excitation gap closes at a second-order quantum phase transition, there is usually a characteristic velocity (the speed of sound) that acts as a effective speed of light. The system has emergent Lorentz symmetry near the critical point, so it becomes effectively relativistic but with a material-dependent speed of sound taking the place of the (completely universal) speed of light.  We can use this velocity to relate distance and imaginary time.